# Web services which offer free data in JSONP format

Tags: web-services, jsonp, mashup

For example, Google provides dictionary definitions for English words in JSONP format from the following URL:

http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=a&sl=en&tl=en&restrict=pr,de&client=te&q=internet

Do you know other JSONP sources of interesting free information on the Internet, which could be useful to create mash-up webs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check out Programmableweb's API directory

https://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory

I believe they are trying to be the Git Hub of APIs. They have over 13,000 APIs in their registry.

Should be very easy to find sources to mash up.  =)

Comment: I can't vote you up because of my "low reputation" in stackoverflow :), but... thanks!